# Wordpress 404 issue after Migration in Plesk (Nginx config issue)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, putty, plesk, permalinks

I recently migrated my website to DigitalOcean under plesk panel using all in one migration plugin. I kept having issues with 404 error only for pages that used permalinks configured as %postname%. For better URL format for my Content. But now if I enable the permalink I keep getting 404 error.

I used the popular suggestion of editing the nginx conf file through (through putty).
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-nginx-for-wordpress-permalinks/

I wasn't sure of the save and exit step given after using the editor. ctrl+X shows a set of ^O^D commands. I pressed ^O and restarted it.

Now my entire website looks broken. Due to many 500 internal errors. What am I doing wrong here? kindly help me out please?

My website address is https://ourmoon.life/

Comment: I just resolved the problem with the site breaking with 500. The htaccess is not being properly read anymore. had to remove the rule that redirects the index.php for it work properly now.

Comment: https://ourmoon.life/universe-researcher/
as the 500 issue is now resolved. The problem is mainly with the 404 pages when the %postname% permalink is activated. Is there any nginx directive that I can configure to fix this issue? or is altering the nginx.conf the only way.